# Copy variable length structs to buffer

Tags: c, dynamic, struct, malloc

I want to copy variable length structs to a buffer. My struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct{
    int flag;
    int size;
    unsigned char name[0];
} sp;
```

I do not know the size of name in advance. After I get `size` I malloc this struct by:

```
sp *s = malloc(sizeof(sp)+size)
```

To copy to a buffer, I do this:

```
char *buf = calloc(1000, sizeof(*buf));
memcpy(buf, s, sizeof(sp)); //s is of type sp with all memebers initialized
```

My buffer remains empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sizeof(sp)` does not change because the block of memory allocated for `name` is not part of `sp`. `sp` contains only a *pointer* to the memory where `name` is stored.

Comment: So memcpy should have `size+sizeof(sp)`?

Comment: My mistake. It should be unsigned char name[0]

Comment: This is where you are memcpying apples and oranges. Your struct consists of 2 `ints` and and `unsigned char *`. The block of memory holding `name` is elsewhere. You are essentially attempting a *shallow* copy of `sp` expecting it to also copy `name`. It won't. You have to copy both `sp` and `name`.

Comment: `sizeof *buf` is not valid for `void *`

Comment: Correcting this. You're right.

Comment: `unsigned char name[0]` is not valid in ISO C either, but you can write `unsigned char name[];`  . Some compilers treat the `[0]` version the same as the standard version.

Comment: When editing the question, including the posted code, always indicate the old and new text so the older comments do not lead to confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want to declare `name` as array of pointers, but instead an array of `char`s.

```
typedef struct {
    int flag;
    int size;
    char name[];
} sp;
```

Then you can create an instance like this.

```
int size = 10;
sp *s = malloc(sizeof(sp)+size);
s->flag = 0;
s->size = size;
strncpy(s->name, "Hello!", size);
s->name[size - 1] = '\0'; // Make sure name is NULL-terminated
```

You can copy the structure into a buffer as follows.

```
void *buf = calloc(1000, 1);
memcpy(buf, s, sizeof(s)+ s->size);
```

Print out the names as follows to check it worked.

```
printf("Name is %s.\n", s->name);
printf("The buffer's copy of name is %s.\n", ((sp*)buf)->name);
```

Comment: This is inadvisable use of `strncpy` as if the buffer size is exceeded then it does not null-terminate the string, leading to bugs.

Comment: In this case, the literal `"Hello!"` is guaranteed to fit in a 10-byte buffer. But I'll add a NULL for safety in case someone were to change the string.

Comment: OP's struct is using `unsigned char` so this means the data could [easily] be binary. Thus, I'd stick with `memcpy` and avoid `str*` for `name`. As defined, `name` could contain anything

Comment: Using the array size 0 is not standard; it might be a GCC extension (or some other compiler).  You should show a flexible array member instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler AFAIK it was standard in GCC but has been adopted in c99.

Comment: No; the C99 standard allows `unsigned char name[];` with no size specified — that's a _flexible array member_.  It does not allow zero size objects.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Answer changed to use the flexible array syntax.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right. I was confused :)